# SetInterval set to 10ms is taking more than spected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, settimeout, setinterval

I am trying to create a stopwatch in my app and to do this I am setting an interval to run every 10ms and inside the function that is run every 10ms I update the time. The problem here is that when I run it, the centiseconds (10ms) go really slow, as if I had put 100ms.

```
const HomeScreen = ({ route, navigation }: Props) => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState({ ms: 0, s: 0, m: 0 });
  const [interv, setInterv] = useState();
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(0);
  // Not started = 0
  // started = 1
  // stopped = 2

  const start = () => {
    run();
    setStatus(1);
    setInterv(setInterval(run, 10));
  };

  var updatedMs = time.ms,
    updatedS = time.s,
    updatedM = time.m;

  const run = () => {
    if (updatedS === 60) {
      updatedM++;
      updatedS = 0;
    }
    if (updatedMs === 100) {
      updatedS++;
      updatedMs = 0;
    }
    updatedMs++;
    return setTime({ ms: updatedMs, s: updatedS, m: updatedM });
  };

  const stop = () => {
    clearInterval(interv);
    setStatus(2);
  };

  const reset = () => {
    clearInterval(interv);
    setStatus(0);
    setTime({ ms: 0, s: 0, m: 0 });
  };

  const resume = () => start();

  ...
```

Comment: "Go really slow"?

Comment: @JMadelaine Yes, as if I had put 100ms instead of 10ms. Any question?

Comment: can your mention your computer specs, its maybe have an heavy load on your processor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with setInterval is it depends on the engine processing the code and various other loads.